# Fatal: Cannot open file. Error: ppcx64.exe returned an error code

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, pascal, freepascal

My code and Visual Studio Code's error message:

[image: 1]

Why in Visual Studio Code I can't compile Pascal file but it working properly on FPC IDE or Sublime Text 4 with ObjectPascal package?

My file dir:

```
d:\Programming\Pascal\Learning\Boi_Duong\#9_Buoi9.pas
```

Error message:

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2 [2021/05/15] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling #9_Buoi9.pas
Fatal: Cannot open file "#9_Buoi9.pas"
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: C:\FPC\3.2.2\bin\i386-Win32\ppc386.exe returned an error exitcode
```

Comment: The prompt afterwards doesn't show any directory change. Is that command valid cmd.exe syntax? Also the path with quotes in it looks dodgy.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort As you can see, the problem was came from the ppcx64.exe from the FPC. FPC was called at the right way and no syntax error in compiling command.
The Error notification is: 
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2 [2021/05/15] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling #9_Buoi9.pas
Fatal: Cannot open file "#9_Buoi9.pas"
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: C:\FPC\3.2.2\bin\i386-Win32\ppc386.exe returned an error exitcode
The pascal file directory is:
d:\Programming\Pascal\Learning\Boi_Duong\#9_Buoi9.pas

Comment: But the errormessage contains "d:\Programming\Pascal\Learning\Boi_Duong\"#9_Buoi9.pas   not  "d:\Programming\Pascal\Learning\Boi_Duong\#9_Buoi9.pas" as it should. IOW it is logical that FPC doesn't eat this (btw ppc386<>ppcx64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set you default terminal to Command Prompt: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open Command Palette, find Terminal: Select your default profile. Then choose Command Prompt.

Then, you need to configure your compiling command in settings.json for Code Runner extension. Open settings.json by press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and add this setting:

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "pascal": "fpc $fullFileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
},
```